# This PHP code refreshes a simple log, how can I get an "OK" when data has been successfully posted?

Tags: php, logging, server

this is my first time using PHP, so I'm here because I don't even know how to look for the information I want (function name's, properties, etc). As I said before, my code receives a string with two variables and uploads it to a log with the format:

Raw time data, var1, var2

So, I want to add some lines that allow the code to send an "OK" confirmation when data has been successfully posted. How can I get it?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
echo "<pre>";
echo "hello! \n";
$file = 'measures.txt';
$time = time();
$row = "$time";
if ( isset( $_GET["T"] ) )
{
    $new_measure = $_GET["T"];
    echo "Temperature: $new_measure \n";
    $row = $row.", $new_measure";
} else {
    $row = $row.", ";
}
if ( isset( $_GET["H"] ) )
{
    $new_measure = $_GET["H"];
    echo "Humidity: $new_measure \n";
    $row = $row.", $new_measure";
} else {
    $row = $row.", ";
}
file_put_contents($file, "$row\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: When in doubt about how functions work consult php.net, for this example, http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php. Put your `file_put_contents` in a conditional. On `true` output `Ok`. You'll be better off learning databases, or additionally.

Answer (score 0):

Julio,

in your file_put_contents function you could simply echo a " OK" message if the file is successfully stored in the location you set. Now if you are trying to do email confirmation you would need to setup a mail function within your php application and have the proper smtp configurations so your server can do that.

I am assuming you have verification checks before the file is given to your file_put_contents function.